# How can I do a massive and complex string replace in a PHP project?

Tags: php, regex, eclipse, string

I guess "in a file tree" would suffice but this is my case.

I'm given a task to replace all instances of

`some_function('string_parameter'.$some_optional_var.');`

to

`some_function().'string_parameter'.$some_optional_var.';` in a PHP project.

The parameter can be different in any place the function is being called.

I'm pretty sure I can user regex or something like that but regex is not my strength...

I'm using Eclipse Indigo if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: The parameter of the function is not the same in all cases. I updated my question

Comment: Do a dry run first, and search for a pattern like this: `some_function([^)]+);`

Comment: The eclipse search returned me results like some_function[''] and window.location = some_function+'blah'...

Comment: I thought you were asking a programming question, not how to use your IDE.  Write a little PHP script (or Perl).

Comment: @DavidO, you need to escape the parentheses in your regex in order to match actual parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me in Eclipse search and replace.

Search:

```
some_function\(([^)]+)\)
```

Replace:

```
some_function().$1
```

(This puts the content inside the call to `some_function` after it, no matter what that content is.  If this isn't specific enough, you will need to describe exactly what kind of cases of `some_function` you need to handle.)

You need to turn on the regex option, obviously.

**Explanation:**

`some_function` matches that exact text.

`\( ... \)` since parentheses are a special character in regexes, a backslash is needed to escape them so that we match actual parentheses.

`(...)` the inner parentheses create a capture group to record what this portion of the regex matches.

`[^)]+` a character class matching one or more characters that are not parentheses (the `^` negates a character class; the `+` requires there to be at least one character, and matches as many as possible.

`$1` in the replacement--inserts the value captured in the parentheses above.  You can capture many different things with different groups of parentheses, and they will go into `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Comment: Just one notice: It the some_function takes another function as parameter, this will lead to some weird results. Like some_function('Text'.some_other_function('text')) will turn to some_function().some_other_function().'text' but this happened only a few times in my code so it was easy to fix by hand :)

Comment: @Loupax, yes, good point.  I didn't about that case.  It would actually be nearly impossible to make a regex that would handle all cases correctly. It would have to allow an arbitrary number of nested functions.  And what about parentheses inside strings or comments?  I'm glad this worked pretty well for you, though.